# Measure size of largest connected component in QGIS

Tags: qgis, network

I'm doing network analysis to measure robustness against disruption through largest connected component. Currently I only have two types of file which consist of road segment and road junction. I know there are several software packages that could be used to do that, but I'm not an advanced user in this field.

Is there a way to define the largest connected component using only QGIS and one of its available plugins?

I want to know where is the largest connected component in my network, which one, and how many connected junctions inside that component.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [v.net.components](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.net.components.html)?